# How to loop over $@ in pairs in Bash?

Tags: bash

How to do I write a loop in bash, that does something like below:

```
for (i=0; i< len("$@"); i+=2) {
    print a[i], a[i+1]
    // do stuff using the pair elements.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of indexing into `$@`, the easy (and POSIX-compatible) approach is to simply shift things off the beginning as you go:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  echo "$1, $2"
  shift; shift
done
```

If you really do want to index instead, and don't mind being specific to shells (like bash) adopting extensions pioneered by ksh:

```
# start at 1 to avoid $0
# quotes in immediately below line because SO syntax highlighter doesn't know bash
for ((i=1; i<("$#" + 1); i+=2)); do
  echo "${@:i:1}, ${@:i+1:1}"
done
```

Comment: Yeah, bash is great, I use it, but I don't put bashisms in scripts either.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, I'm obviously a bit more willing to put bashisms in scripts (some of them let you do things robustly that can't be made as reliable when depending on POSIX-mandated functionality only), but I at least try to do so in places where they add some value. :)

Comment: Sure, you might have a problem not solved well by the core shell, a compromise between macro processor and programming language. That's when I switch to Ruby, lol.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, people who use the shell as if it were a souped-up macro processor are one of my largest sources of headaches. The core defining attribute of a macro processor is recursive textual substitution into code. If the shell did that, it would be **impossible** to write secure code in shell handling untrustworthy data -- which isn't the case.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, ...though I do agree that there's a time to switch to a better language; I'd tend to call Go a better choice than Ruby if correctness and predictability are what you're aiming for, though. :)